# Mongoose throws CastError: Cast to string failed for value "[ 'pending', 'in-progress', 'finished' ]" (type Array)

Tags: typescript, mongodb, api, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose with Next.js, atm I'm trying to initially seed the database by hitting the `localhost:3000/api/seed` endpoint, but I'm getting an error. Insomnia gives me a `500 Internal Server Error`. This is the output in the terminal in VSCode:

```bash
error - CastError: Cast to string failed for value "[ 'pending', 'in-progress', 'finished' ]" (type Array) at path "status"
    at SchemaString.cast (C:\TMP\_coding-important\03-open-jira\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:603:11)
    at SchemaString.enum (C:\TMP\_coding-important\03-open-jira\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:238:33)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType (C:\TMP\_coding-important\03-open-jira\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:115:18)
    at new SchemaString (C:\TMP\_coding-important\03-open-jira\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:28:14)
    at Schema.interpretAsType (C:\TMP\_coding-important\03-open-jira\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:1274:22)
    at Schema.path (C:\TMP\_coding-important\03-open-jira\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:900:27)
    at Schema.add (C:\TMP\_coding-important\03-open-jira\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:654:14)
    at new Schema (C:\TMP\_coding-important\03-open-jira\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:133:10)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./models/Entry.ts:8:21)
    at Object.(api)/./models/Entry.ts (C:\TMP\_coding-important\03-open-jira\.next\server\pages\api\seed.js:62:1) {
  stringValue: `"[ 'pending', 'in-progress', 'finished' ]"`,
  messageFormat: undefined,
  kind: 'string',
  value: [ 'pending', 'in-progress', 'finished' ],
  path: 'status',
  reason: null,
  valueType: 'Array'
```

This is my code: ...

model/Entry.ts

```js
import mongoose, { Model, Schema } from "mongoose";
import { Entry } from "../interfaces";

interface IEntry extends Entry {}

const entrySchema = new Schema({
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Number },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
      value: ["pending", "in-progress", "finished"],
      message: "{VALUE} is not an allowed state",
    },
  },
});

const EntryModel: Model<IEntry> = mongoose.models.Entry || mongoose.model("Entry", entrySchema);

export default EntryModel;
```

database/seed-data.ts

```js
interface SeedData {
  entries: SeedEntry[];
}

interface SeedEntry {
  description: string;
  status: string;
  createdAt: number;
}

export const seedData: SeedData = {
  entries: [
    {
      description:
        "pending: Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto inventore accusamus nulla harum?",
      status: "pending",
      createdAt: Date.now(),
    },
    {
      description:
        "in-progress: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quam illo eligendi id.",
      status: "in-progress",
      createdAt: Date.now() - 1000000,
    },
    {
      description:
        "finished: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam quos necessitatibus distinctio repellendus.",
      status: "finished",
      createdAt: Date.now() - 100000,
    },
  ],
};
```

pages/api/seed.ts

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { db } from "../../database";
import { seedData } from "../../database/seed-data";
import { Entry } from "../../models";

type Data = {
  message: string;
};

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Access to service not allowed" });
  }

  await db.connect();
  await Entry.deleteMany();
  await Entry.insertMany(seedData.entries)
  await db.disconnect();

  res.status(200).json({ message: "Process executed successfully" });
}
```

I've tried looking up the issue and in most cases it involves how the property `enum` is used incorrectly when defining the type in the schema...

However, I'm pretty new to this and haven't got a clue how to proceed XD Hence why I'm posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not that good in Typescript. You can create a enum and assign it to the schema and use this enum also for the document.

```
export enum Status {
    PENDING = 'pending',
    IN_PROGRESS = 'in-progress',
    FINISHED = 'finished'
}

const entrySchema = new Schema({
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Number },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: Status,
    default: Status.PENDING
  },
});
```

```
interface SeedData {
  entries: SeedEntry[];
}

interface SeedEntry {
  description: string;
  status: string;
  createdAt: number;
}

export const seedData: SeedData = {
  entries: [
    {
      description:
        "pending: Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto inventore accusamus nulla harum?",
      status: Status.PENDING,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
    },
    {
      description:
        "in-progress: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quam illo eligendi id.",
      status: Status.IN_PROGRESS,
      createdAt: Date.now() - 1000000,
    },
    {
      description:
        "finished: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam quos necessitatibus distinctio repellendus.",
      status: Status.FINISHED,
      createdAt: Date.now() - 100000,
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Thank you se very much! This solved it and allowed to seed the database correctly!

Comment: If your question was answered please accept my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I just did! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Following the same line of code, with much more time for looking up the cause of my mistake, I found out that I was missing something.

When setting up the `enum`, I set up the property `value`, when it should have been `values`:

```js
enum: {
      value: ["pending", "in-progress", "finished"],
      message: "{VALUE} is not an allowed state",
},
```

Though this is the most precise answer because it actually addresses the error in my OP, I marked [ratzownal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14125569/ratzownal)'s answer as the best one since it also worked and he was so quick to respond. Credit where credit is due.

I'm simply adding this for future reference.